# More accurate curve fitting

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I did a curve fitting by using curve_fit function in scipy.
But, curve fitting was not good to me. Is there any way to improve the curve fitting?
Below python code is what I wrote.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

minus_eta_total =[-0.004, -0.0116, -0.02604, -0.04, -0.08, -0.12, -0.16, -0.2, -0.24, -0.288, -0.3456, -0.4]

I_d_infil_0_sub_1 = [0.004204675, 0.012262849, 0.028331318, 0.045626793, 0.113222124, 0.224759087, 0.403571293, 0.678854397, 1.090002487, 1.837299526, 3.260471157, 5.311900419]
ASR_el = 0.0075

eta_infil_0_sub_1 = np.array(minus_eta_total) + (np.array(I_d_infil_0_sub_1)*np.array(ASR_el))

cons_eq = 8.3144 * 1073 / (0.5 * 4 * 96485)

def func(x, a, b):
    return -cons_eq*np.log(x/a)-b*x

popt_infil_0_sub_1, pcov_infil_0_sub_1 = curve_fit(func, I_d_infil_0_sub_1, eta_infil_0_sub_1)

plt.clf()

plt.plot(I_d_infil_0_sub_1, eta_infil_0_sub_1, linestyle = '--',  marker='o', color='k', label = 'original')
plt.plot(I_d_infil_0_sub_1, func(np.asarray(I_d_infil_0_sub_1),*popt_infil_0_sub_1), 'k', label='fit: $\mathit{j_0}$=%5.4f, R$_{ohm}$=%5.4f' % tuple(popt_infil_0_sub_1))

plt.ylim(-0.42, 0.02)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 12, 2))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, -0.42, -0.05))
plt.xlabel('$\mathit{j}$ ($A/cm^2$)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('-\u03b7$_c$ (V)', fontsize=14)  # \u03bcm = micro(\u03bc) + meter(m)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show(block = False)
```

Comment: In what sense was it not good for you? (hint: that's usually the problem, you need to convey the kind of curve fitting you want to the algorithm)

Comment: I tried your code with initial parameter estimates provided by scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm, and that yielded the same fit that you have - that is, it was not better than curve_fit's default parameter estimates of all 1,0. The only way I know to improve the fit is to use a different equation, which I can suggest -  would that be of any use in your work?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I tried to do with the equation like y = -A*ln(x/a)-B*x, but the fitted plot did not reflect the points well. Is there better way to fit more accurate?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I should think about other equation that I can use. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The fitting is not so good than expected probably because the chosen equation is not quite convenient.

For example, if we chose the equation :

y(x)=(exp(-a*x)-1)/a

and criteria of fitting : Least mean square relative error,

a=10.17

The result is MSRE=0.052

This is a very good resut considering a so simple equatioon with one parameter only.

Of course, more accurate fit can certainly be achieved in choosing a more complicated equation with more adjustable parameters.

[image]